# Get file content from specific position to another specific position

Tags: c++, file

I want a part of file content by specifying the beginning of position and specifying the end of position.

I'm using `seekg` function to do that, but the function only determine the beginning position, but how determine the end position.

I'm did code to get the content of file from specific position to end of file, and save each line in item of array.

```
ifstream file("accounts/11619.txt");
if(file != NULL){
   char *strChar[7];
   int count=0;
   file.seekg(22); // Here I have been determine the beginning position
   strChar[0] = new char[20];
   while(file.getline(strChar[count], 20)){
      count++;
      strChar[count] = new char[20];
}
```

For example
**The following is the file content:**

```
11619.
Mark Zeek.
39.
beside Marten st.
2/8/2013.
0
```

**I want to get only the following part:**

```
39.
beside Marten st.
2/8/2013.
```

Comment: Oh please, use `std::string` and `std::getline`.

Comment: @Nawaz: but I want to use c-style string.

Comment: if you know the **beginning position** and the **end position**, can't you just calculate the number of characters to read, and pass it as the second parameter in [`getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you know the start and end of the block you want to read from the file you can use `ifstream::read()`.

```
std::ifstream file("accounts/11619.txt");
if(file.is_open())
{
    file.seekg(start);
    std::string s;
    s.resize(end - start);
    file.read(&s[0], end - start);
}
```

Or if you *insist* on using naked pointers and managing the memory yourself...

```
std::ifstream file("accounts/11619.txt");
if(file.is_open())
{
    file.seekg(start);
    char *s = new char[end - start + 1];
    file.read(s, end - start);
    s[end - start] = 0;

    // delete s somewhere
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use c-style string.

Comment: @LionKing Can you not use s.c_str(), or use char * instead of string;

Comment: @LionKing Not sure why you insist on using naked pointers but I've updated my example.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious: Can you please, tell me what is the benefit of `s[end - start] = 0;` ?

Comment: @LionKing it adds a null terminator to the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Read the reference for [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/).  In the `seekg` function, they define some `ios_base` stuff you want.  I think you're looking for:

```
file.seekg(0,ios_base::end)
```

Edit:  Or perhaps you want this?  (Taken straight from the [tellg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/) reference, modified a bit to read a random block that I pulled out of thin air).

```
// read a file into memory
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {
  std::ifstream is ("test.txt", std::ifstream::binary);
  if (is) {
    is.seekg(-5,ios_base::end); //go to 5 before the end
    int end = is.tellg(); //grab that index
    is.seekg(22); //go to 22nd position
    int begin = is.tellg(); //grab that index

    // allocate memory:
    char * buffer = new char [end-begin];

    // read data as a block:
    is.read (buffer,end-begin); //read everything from the 22nd position to 5 before the end

    is.close();

    // print content:
    std::cout.write (buffer,length);

    delete[] buffer;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know `ios_base::end`, and I don't want read to the end of file. I want a part of file content from specific file offset to specific file offset.

Comment: ... you mean [tellg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/)?  I'm sure that reference tells you what you want to know...

Answer (score 1):

first you can use

```
seekg()
```

to set the reading position, then you can use

```
read(buffer,length)
```

to read the intent.

for example you want to read 10 characters begin from the 6th characters in a text file called test.txt following is an example.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
std::ifstream is ("test.txt", std::ifstream::binary);
if(is)
{
is.seekg(0, is.end);
int length = is.tellg();
is.seekg(5, is.beg);

char * buffer = new char [length];

is.read(buffer, 10);

is.close();

cout << buffer << endl;

delete [] buffer;
}
return 0;
}
```

but in your situation ,why not use getline()?